# Receiving UDP broadcast

Tags: c++, udp

I have to receive an UDP broadcast (in Ubuntu if that makes any difference). Using Wireshark, I can see the packet being sent from the server machine, and I can see it being received by my client machine, but my program is completely oblivious. This is what I have:

```
sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
int s;
assert((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))!=-1);
int port=6000;
int broadcast=1;

setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,
            &broadcast, sizeof broadcast);

memset(&si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_me.sin_port = htons(port);
si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

assert(::bind(s, (sockaddr *)&si_me, sizeof(sockaddr))!=-1);

while(1)
{
    char buf[10000];
    unsigned slen=sizeof(sockaddr);
    recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 0, (sockaddr *)&si_other, &slen);

    printf("recv: %s\n", buf);
}
```

It is compiled in debug mode, the asserts aren't being erased during compilation, and my program just blocks on `recvfrom`.

Is there any other hoop I have to jump through to receive an untargeted UDP broadcast?

Edit: just a bit more info, I have the two computers connected on a dedicated switch, no outside interference. I also have a second network card on my client computer that connects to the company network, which also works.

I can ping both the outside (Internet working) and my server machine (plus I can see the actual packets in Wireshark), but you never know what might cause this problem.

Comment: This code works for me (after slight modification to make it compile with a C compile).  Possible the `bind` is binding to the wrong interface?  What does `netstat -an | grep 6000` return on the client machine?

Comment: Yeah it's supposed to work, but it doesn't for me. `netstat -an` is showing no open 6000 port, I already double checked that (I also tried using the "reuse" udp flag).

Comment: `bind()` does not actually open a port. Only `connect()` and `listen()` do that. But you do not need to open a port via `listen()` in order to receive UDP broadcasts.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Certainly bind() opens a port. Have a look at netstat after you call it. connect() on the other hand has no visible effect at all.

Comment: Since UDP is connection-less, `connect()` on a UDP socket merely establishes a static association inside the socket handle between the local and remote IP/Port pairs, nothing more.  I was referring to TCP when I mentioned that `connect()` opens a port. Calling `bind()` on a UDP socket adds the bound IP/Port to the netstat list but it does not display any state, which is probably true of all UDP connections.

Comment: Blindy - have you tried using `select()` to detect inbound data before calling `recvfrom()`?  Have you tried using Wireshark to verify that broadcast data is actually arriving on the IP/Port that your socket is bound to?

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is all very inaccurate. connect() does a bind() if it has never been done for the socket, in both UDP and TCP, and this where the port gets opened, in both UDP and TCP. Not in connect() itself. UDP ports show up in netstat as soon as they are bound, implicitly or explicitly. There is no UDP state for netstat to display: the port is either open or not, period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out my code is perfectly fine, as I thought it would be. There was a problem with the network setup itself.

For posterity, I had set up two static IP'd computers on their own hub, instead of using the built in DHCP server on the server machine to allocate the IP address for the other computer. Pretty localized for my problem but you never know..

Answer (score 0):

To send and receive broadcast

1. Be sure that netmask is correct. in windows mask for broadcast packets does not matters, but not in linux.
2. bind socket to INADDR_ANY
3. setsockopt to BROADCAST
4. call sendto with sendaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("your_interface_broadcast_address").
   or - call sento several times for each interface with its broadcast ip address.
5. call recvfrom. any time before calling recvfrom, set up length parameter.

Comment: Why post this? You can see I've done exactly this in my original message from 2012...