# C++ Receiving UDP broadcast packets

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

I have written a UDP broadcaster program to broadcast packets on the subnet 192.168.1.255, port 19000 - let's say it runs on Machine A 192.168.1.26. This is based on http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#broadcast. With error checking removed, it looks like:

```
struct hostent* he = gethostbyname("192.168.1.255");

int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

int broadcast = 1;
int errors = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(int));

struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*) he->h_addr);
memset(addr.sin_zero, '\n', sizeof(addr.sin_zero));

const char* message = "Hi there";
int len = strlen(message);
int bytes_sent = sendto(fd, data, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

I have written a corresponding receiver application to be distributed on machines on the same network as the broadcaster. This is based on http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#datagram. Again, with error checking removed, this program looks like this:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

struct addrinfo* servinfo;
int rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, "19000", &hints, &servinfo);

int fd = -1;
struct addrinfo* p;
for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
{
    fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);

    int errors = bind(fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);

    int broadcast = 1;
    errors |= setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(int));

    if (errors == 0)
         break;
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

struct sockaddr their_addr;
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(their_addr);

int bufsize = 4096;
char buf[bufsize];


int bytes_received = recvfrom(fd, &buf[0], bufsize, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &their_addr, &addr_len);
```

When I run the broadcaster, in Wireshark I can see packets delivered to other machines on the subnet with the expected source address 192.168.1.26 and destination address 192.168.1.255. The payload is correct. However, my receiver application does not pick up the packets.

If I change the broadcaster to send only to a single receiver machine, e.g. 192.168.1.58, the receiver application on that machine receives the packets correctly but obviously no other machine does.

I have disabled the firewalls on both machines.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

Comment: Did you set the setsockopt `SO_BROADCAST` on both side ?  If you bind your receiving socket to the adress `INADDR_ANY`, do you receive broadcast message ?
Double check your network configuration, routing etc... Sometimes network error can be tricky

Comment: You can also use `SO_BINDTODEVICE` to bind your socket  to a specific network interface.

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531975/4234243

Comment: @Clonk - yes you can see from the code above that I have set SO_BROADCAST on both sides. I tried using SO_BINDTODEVICE to force a specific interface but that didn't help.

Comment: If you bind receiving socket to `INADDR_ANY` does it work ? Your code looks fine so it's probably coming from your network configuration. Check everything in your network configuration (mask, route, gateway etc.). I suggest writing a [small python script](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) to send a few bytes over UDP network and see if that works.

Comment: @Clonk - good call. My broadcast address was 192.255.255.255, which I had thought would broadcast to everything on the 192. subnet. If I change this to 192.168.1.255, I receive the packets on my receiver. Thank you!